# requestFileSystem never returns Cordova 3.4 on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I am in the process of updating my cordova app which was last released in January - prior to the significant changes to the File plugin. All is working fine in ripple (old style), but when run on the iOS simulator or iOS device (iOS 7.1), my window.requestFileSystem call will never return (neither fail nor succeed). This behaviour occurs for both persistent and temporary file systems.

I am guessing I have some configuration problem. However, I have tried everything to no avail. Adding console messages I find the window.requestFileSystem call in my code does call requestFileSystem in the requestFileSystem.js of the plugin. I also find the CDVFile methods are all called (in this order: initWithWebView, pluginInitialize, getExtraFileSystemsPreference, getAvailableFileSystems, registerExtraFileSystems (which registers library, library-nosync, documents, documents-nosync, cache, bundle, root)).

However, the exec call in requestFileSystem.js to "requestFileSystem" simply never returns and doesn't ever execute the method in CDVFile. (Note that this is after a deviceready event has returned.)

Any suggestions on what might be wrong or how to debug further at this point?

Comment: What version of the File plugin are you using?

Comment: Using the latest released version (1.1.0)

Comment: Update: still struggling with filesystem issues in general. However, the issue with requestFileSystem never returning doesn't happen if I immediately call it after deviceready (as opposed to later). My app is using jquery mobile and backbone - and various other libraries - but at this point don't know what might be causing this behaviour.

Comment: You do have to wait for a deviceReady event to fire before using the File plugin -- but are you saying that this would fail: `setTimeout(someFunctionThatRequestsFileSystem, 10000)`? That is, deviceReady would certainly be called within 10s, but that you would get no response when the timeout expired?

Comment: Also, might be worth eliminating all your other libraries (even if in a demo project) to get to the root of the issue. It could be some other library getting in the way

Comment: I am always calling requestFileSystem AFTER deviceready, and yes I was having it never returning. However, at this point I can no longer reproduce this problem! I also encountered other strange problems like getDirectory (called off the root Directory Entry with create true, exclusive false) never returning. Unfortunately, I have  not been able to determine the exact conditions of when it occurs as  the problems appear intermittent! In general, I have found that using the latest file plugin on Android works just fine, but have struggled with flakiness on iOS (both on Simulator and Device).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue encountered here was not directly related to the file system plugin. The reason the requestFileSystem (or other File Plugin calls like getDirectory referred to above) were never returning was ultimately the cordova.exec call never returning - which would happen anytime AFTER the console plugin (org.apache.cordova.console) was loaded (then any subsequent cordova.exec call would just hang). Removing the console plugin fixed my issues.

Why removing the console plugin was the fix I am less certain. However, I do have my own logger.js which may be interfering somehow with the console plugin? Hopefully this is an issue specific to my code. Not sure why this was only an issue for me on iOS and not Android.

Comment: I know the cordova console plugin has to do different things on iOS/Android, and so that's probably why you saw differing behavior. If you can replicate exactly what's causing the issue in your code, perhaps you should submit an issue so that the plugin can be better shielded against things like that (or at least it can be made well known what *not* to do)?